# Custom paragraph prefixed with number?

Tags: views

I am looking at different CMS's and KMS's for suitable software user documentation systems. Im very impressed with Drupal.

I have a user case where I would like to be able to add a series of steps - so a user can read the steps and actions needed to take to complete a task.

I thought this could be achieved using [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs). However, I would like to have a sequential number at the beginning of each paragraph, eg:

1. Do step one
2. Add a widget
3. Enable the gadget

How would I do this in Drupal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the CSS? What about a CSS solution?

http://bl.ocks.org/trauber/5163440

```
.paragraph-parent {
    counter-reset: paragraph;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.paragraph-parent p {
    width: 75%;
}
.paragraph-parent p:before {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    content: counter(paragraph);
    counter-increment: paragraph;
}
```